# Adding Heap Analytics code in React Project

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, heap-analytics

I am trying to add heap analytics script in my react project but it keeps throwing this error "'heap' is not defined". And I cannot compile the project due to this error.

As far as I know, heap wants their code to run in `<head></head>` tags. But I can't figure out how to make a code run inside `<head></head>` in react. The rest of the scripts like GTM and FB pixel code is running fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to run functions from heap inside your react scripts?

Comment: @Felix yeah I want to run the Heap analytics script in the project, and that includes heap analytics' function

Comment: yes but do they need to run inside your react project? otherwise you could just insert them in the head tag

Comment: I want to insert that script in the head tag but I cant find that markup of head tag in the project. This script is being run from a component which gets added in the body.

Comment: Do you run webpack or anything alike which have an html-generator? otherwise there must be anywhere an html-document where you can simply add an head and your scripts.

Comment: there is index.html which is in public folder. And yes I do use webpack.

Comment: Then just put your script in there and ask in your scipts if the variable is defined before using them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to include the heap script under head tag as below (*Set right path to script in place of yourHeapScriptPath*)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourHeapScriptPath.js"></script>
```

Comment: but head tag in which file? index.js or index.html or do i have to create a new component that inserts that script in head tag.

Comment: Do you have root html element is index.html? If so, you should be able to add the script tag within head in index.html

Comment: Yes, this solution is working but if I am trying to add it directly in the footer component it is not working. Anyways this one worked and I added taht script as external js file in the index.html file in public folder.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason this isn't more clear on their website but if you check their docs [here](https://help.heap.io/define-analyze/react-dom-minification/using-heap-with-react-websites/) then you'll see that you just have to call `window.heap.track()` not just `heap.track()`.

Also, you want the script as they mention in your `index.html` file at the bottom of the `<head>` element aka right before `</head>`

Answer (score 2):

Just call it off:

```
window.heap.identify('random@myemail.com', 'email');
```

Answer (score 0):

If your're using webpack, you've got two options:

A) put your script in index.html and ask in your React-Scripts if the variables are defined
B) Put the scripts in your webpack entries, like the following:

```
const config = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/app.js',
    vendors: './src/vendors.js'
  }
};
```

See [webpack-entries](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/) for more information.